# Why do I get unexpected coordinates after converting EPSG 102014 to EPSG 4326?

Tags: coordinate-system, convert, epsg

I have this [Europe map](http://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/custom/europe.js) (EPSG 102014) and I am trying to convert it to EPSG 4326 using geoconverter.hsr.ch

After the conversion is done, I expect that coordinates are in the range of -180,180 and -90,90, but instead, I get this range: 10.00,10.10 and 30.00,30.10.

If you check [this example here](http://bl.ocks.org/d/24998cdb7a6d65f7815e), you can see that the countries have the same shape, it's all looking great, but they are all concentrated in a tiny area of Africa.

How can I convert between the two EPSGs and get the right latitude and longitude?

Comment: could you provide the ELCC coordinates of some know point (big cities): it could be that your input coordinate system is not correct.

Comment: It could be that EPSG:102014 doesn't exist, while ESRI:102014 does. May be your converter only accepts standards?

Comment: ESRI:102014 exists in the EPSG official spatial reference lists, so I presume it is standard. I tested the conversion process and converted the GeoJson version of the same data from the same website successfully and compared it to the results I get in QGIS. So, geoconverter honours EPSG:102014. I then repeated the process with the javascript version to duplicate your issue.  However, geoconverter gives me an error "Conversion failed".  So, I suspect the error is with the js version of the data. I recommend you use geojson in this instance or get the original data from www.naturalearthdata.com.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answers, I will also give it a try with QGIS and try to get the data in the right format.

Comment: Why would you expect a European map to expand to a global extent?

Comment: @MappaGnosis No, Esri:102014 doesn't exist in the EPSG Registry--that's why it has an Esri well-known ID, and not an EPSG one. I assume you saw it at spatialreference.org?

Comment: Your input file is for sure json but of some special format. Have a look at it `jsonmarginX":-999,"jsonmarginY":9851.0,"xoffset":-1706316.2597,"yoffset":4824494.18154}}`Coordinates are given as offsets from an anchor point. The coordinate values are small like `[3686,4530]]],[[[3536,4512]`. GDAL which is obviously used in the conversion service just skips the offsets and is using the raw coordinates. I fear that you will need some special tools for the conversion.